# Getting a TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python

My Code:

```
import urllib.request
for num in range(1,31):
    URL= "http://readcomicbooksonline.net/reader/mangas/Batman 2011/Batman Endgame Special Edition/njqr-"
    IMAGE = str(num)+".jpg"
    for i in range(1,(3-int(num/10))):
        IMAGE="0"+IMAGE
    print (IMAGE)
    req = urllib.request.Request(str(URL+IMAGE), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(req, str(IMAGE))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\Books, Papers and Certificates\Comics\Batman\EndGame\downloader.py", line 9, in <module>
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(req, str(IMAGE))
      File "C:\Users\Baidyanath Kundu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 246, in urlretrieve
        url_type, path = splittype(url)
      File "C:\Users\Baidyanath Kundu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 924, in splittype
        match = _typeprog.match(url)
    TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

**Edited** Sorry, my bad I had posted a previous version of the code. I have updated it.

Comment: Could you please describe what you are trying to achieve, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: The stack trace says the error is in line `urllib.request.urlretrieve(req, str(IMAGE))` but that line isn't in your example. I ran your example and got an HTTP "forbidden" error, but the url parsing stuff worked. The problem is in code you don't show.

Comment: I am trying to download all the images from the urls.