# Install jupyterlab in pip3 throws 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

**Background**

- I was trying to install Jupyter Lab using `pip3 install jupyterlab`, and it threw the same error.
- I did not figure it out. Found a workaround using `pip2 install jupyterlab` -- it worked, but clearly was a bandaid fix.
- tried running `import pandas as pd` in the python3 notebook (inside jupyter lab); module was not found.
- I am using Cygwin as my linux emulator on a PC.
- I prefer python3.x over python 2.7.

**My attempts to resolve the issue**

- *Similar reported JupyterLab post* - I found this post here: [Import pandas on jupyter ipython notebook fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253338/import-pandas-on-jupyter-ipython-notebook-fails), but I believe the author is using anaconda (which I am not) and the Type Error is different.
- I found a post relevant to my TypeError, but that's for a code he's writing: [Getting a TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854086/getting-a-typeerror-expected-string-or-bytes-like-object).

I have a hard time interpreting the Traceback, but here it is below:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 487, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 428, in _check_skip_installed
    req_to_install, upgrade_allowed)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 427, in find_all_candidates
    self._package_versions(page.links, search)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 595, in _package_versions
    v = self._link_package_versions(link, search)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 667, in _link_package_versions
    support_this_python = check_requires_python(link.requires_python)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/packaging.py", line 34, in check_requires_python
    return python_version in requires_python_specifier
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/packaging/specifiers.py", line 698, in __contains__
    return self.contains(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/packaging/specifiers.py", line 703, in contains
    item = parse(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 31, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 200, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Why is the version returned not a string or byte? Is there a bug in my python 3.6 package itself? I am thinking about opening up those files in the traceback to see if I can debug it, but I thought I should ask for help before attempting something that sounds a little ridiculous, imo.

**Other things I have tried**

- `pip2 install --upgrade pip` - this returns a message saying pip in python2.7 is up-to-date.

Traceback (pip2):

```
$ pip2 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

- `pip3 install --upgrade pip` - this returns the same TypeError above

Traceback (pip3): *see the first Traceback*

**pip version and python site output**

```
$ pip2 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

$ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/jennings/Documents/hpv/hpv_missed_clinics',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logilab_common-1.3.0-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python27.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-cygwin',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/jennings/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/jennings/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True

$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

$ python3 -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/jennings/Documents/hpv/hpv_missed_clinics',
    '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
    '/home/jennings/Documents/kaggle/SQL_scavenger/src/bq-helper',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/linkgrammar',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/jennings/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/jennings/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Comment: Hmmm, everything looks OK to me and both your pip installations are up to date (9.0.1 is current).

Comment: So, what is the error on `pip3 install jupyterlab` ?

Comment: `pip install jupyterlab` works for me with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and python 3.6. Also `pandas` does not get installed unless you do `pip install pandas`.

Comment: So, someone earlier suggested changing ` match = self._regex.search(version)` to ` match = self._regex.search(str(version))` in my file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/packaging/version.py -- this fixed it ಠ_ಠ. He deleted his comment since and I don't remember his username. This definitely feels like a bandaid fix, but it totally worked..

Comment: @fips Sorry, I should mention that I have been writing code using the pandas module without jupyterlab. Pandas is definitely already installed. After adding the str() bandaid, I re-ran `pip3 install jupyterlab` and now `import pandas as pd` now works inside jupyterlab. If anybody has an insight why my version was not of the type string or byte, I would definitely appreciate the info...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The true fix is just bite the bullet and use virtual environments to ensure packages work, whether that's using `Anaconda-gui`, `conda`, `pipenv`, `poetry` or `venv` directly (you should be able to google).

I was in a time crunch, and the answer below by Wʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 gave me the band-aid to complete what I needed to do. I'm going to leave it here for archival purposes.

---

Per ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 answer in the comments, which was deleted, this fixed it. If you are ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 and see this edit, feel free to make a comment and I can flag it as the 'accepted answer.' Per Greg Schmit's suggestion, I moved the answer to this section too. I'm new to stackexchange, so if you know how to contact ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000, please do help. This is the answer for now unless someone can provide more insight. Not sure if this complication may be cygwin related or not.

- Opened file "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/packaging/version.py"
- Changed the code on line 200 from `match = self._regex.search(version)` to `match = self._regex.search(str(version))`
- Re-ran the code `pip3 install jupyterlab`

Now the python3 pandas module is recognized inside jupyterlab when I run `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Doing this kind of thing is just going to give you more weird package management problems down the line. This kind of thing is very likely why you're in this situation in the first place.

Comment: @user2357112 very fair comment, but it helped me bandaid the situation since time was limited -- I needed to complete my task. FWIW after the project, I'm using virtual environments now. Let me add this to answer.

Comment: @user2357112 It's true that ideally the package would be fixed, however this is one of the reasons I love open source software. Had this been a binary he downloaded, fixing it would be untenably difficult. He was able to fix it himself and that is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

I had some issue with existing `*.egg-info` files, removing those allowed pip to work again

Comment: This fixed my issue

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just removing ~/.local/lib/python3.9/ and reinstalling all my packages. Ended up fixing the issue

Comment: where are those files? I wanted to delete them

Comment: @M.K from my memory, i think they go either in the folder that `pip install` is run from, or, are in the folder setup.py is in, or maybe are siblings to the top level python modules, eg. `foo/__init__.py` might be `foo.egg-info` but i think it takes the name from setuptools, not the module, so check your setup.py

Answer (score 0):

Adding sudo worked for me:

```
sudo pip3 install jupyterlab
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30785245)

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Specifically, when I tried to install the subdependency `psutil`, pip would emit the following error until I ran with sudo: `pip "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"` The underlying reason is totally unclear to me.